# Finding first 20 documents from collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to display first 20 records from collection on one Jframe and next 20 on another frame . I am newbie to MongoDB. please suggest a query to find first 20 and next 20 documents.

Answer (score 17):

On the MongoDB shell you can do:

```
db.collectionName.find( { city: "London" } ).skip( 20 ).limit( 20 );
```

To show the results from document 21 to 40.

Please look at limit and skip: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read/#limit-the-number-of-documents-to-return

I also strongly suggest you go over a tutorial: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/

Comment: I thought this was slow for large collections because of how mongodb indexes data?  So you should be using a range based on timestamp ranges instead for better performance?  E.g., next hour, next day, etc.

Comment: @kenyee, sure, if you can do that that would be better, but it's not nearly possible in every situation.

Answer (score 3):

```
db.getCollection('name of your collection').find({}).limit(20)
```

Answer (score 1):

## This is what I achieved so far

```
function getFirst20Items() {
    let items

    ITEMS_COLLECTION
        .find({})
        .limit(20)
        .sort({id: 1})
        .toArray( (err, allItems) => {
            items = allItems
        })

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(items)
        }, 2000)
    })
}

function getSecond20Items() {
    let items

    ITEMS_COLLECTION
         // gte stands for --> Greater than
        .find({ id: { $gte: 20 } })
        .limit(20)
        .sort({id: 1})
        .toArray( (err, allItems) => {
            items = allItems
        })

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(items)
        }, 2000)
    })
}

app.get('/first/40/products', (req, res) => {
    const all_Items = []

    getFirst20Items()
        .then(items => {
            all_Items.push(...items)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw new CustomError('Could not get Items', err);
        });
    getSecond20Items()
        .then(items => {
            all_Items.push(...items)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw new CustomError('Could not get Items', err);
        });
    setTimeout(() => {
        res.send(all_Items);    
    }, 2000);
});
```

> You can Continue from here in your logic
>
> Hope this helps