# Limit number of rows in mongodb input of Kettle

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

I want to retrieve data in mongodb input by limiting the number of rows.
But I found `$limit` operation is not working in Kettle.

There is a similar post which uses `$maxScan` to solve it ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272198/limit-no-of-rows-in-mongodb-input)). But there are some conditions in my query. For example:

```
{ "$query" : { "type" : " view " } , $orderby : { "time" : -1}, $limit : 100 } // not working
```

The results by using `$maxScan` are completely different. `$maxScan` may only return 10 rows.

How could I solve this problem? And why the `$limit` operation is not supported in Kettle? I think it is a basic operation.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally! I solve this problem by the advise from @Keviswang. We have to use aggregation method providing by MongoDB, and here is the link: [docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation).

In my case, I use this query in MongoDB Input of Kettle, and we also have to choose `Query is aggregation pipline`.

```
{$match: {activity_type: " view "}},
{$sort: {activity_target: -1 } },
{$limit: 10}
```

The following screen shots can help you understand the operations more clear.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the aggregation framework.

Comment: What is the aggregation framework? Could you give me some examples? Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I find the way to solve the problem!